# Connecting a DD-WRT router to a Squid proxy running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, squid, dd-wrt

I am trying to get a Linksys router with the latest DD-WRT (v24-sp2) in my house connected, via Comcast, to an external Squid (v3) proxy that I am running on AWS. When I connect over the WiFi to the DD-WRT router, it connects to the Squid proxy, but I get the nasty message (abbreviated here to show relevant part):

```
While trying to retrieve the URL: /
```

Note the backlash. I get this when I go to a root domain, like www.cnn.com. If I go to a page under a site, like www.cnn.com/today (fake link used for example only), that returns and error like:

```
While trying to retrieve the URL: /today
```

Again, notice the "/today", as if the root domain has been removed, and the string to the right of the domain name is being searched on.

For some background, I have installed Squid as generally as possible, and have done it on two servers with the same results. I get this same error no matter what domain I go to. Also, if I switch my network on my Mac to use this Squid proxy, it works fine. Only the connections from the DD-WRT give this error.

I have tried the [instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Squid_Transparent_Proxy) on the DD-WRT site with no luck. Others seem to have gotten this working well, so I assume I am making a configuration mistake.

Any clues for me? TIA...